# Motorola Freescale mpc564 microcontroller

Tags: debugging, hardware, flash

Im hoping somebody here can give me some advice.  Im trying to read the flash contents of a Mpc564 Motorola MCU.  The flash size is 512KB   The processor was removed from a bad circuit board. Is there a way to read the flash after the MCU has been removed from the board.  Any help would be appreciated.
[image]